# Applying Laplacian smoothing to vertices in a mesh

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, numpy, computational-geometry

I'm totally new in Python and I wrote some code. It is a simple algorithm to smooth objects. I need to find adjacent vertices in mesh and sum their coordinates and after that divide by a number of adjacent vertices. This algorithm is called Laplacian Smoothing.

Could anybody point out how to make it better?

```
n = mesh.VPos.shape[0]
final = []

for i in range(n):
    neighbors = mesh.vertices[i].getVertexNeighbors()
    indices = map(lambda x: x.ID, neighbors)
    z = len(indices)

    help = []
    for j in indices:
        help.append([mesh.VPos[j]])
    final += [sum(x)/z for x in zip(*help)]

final = np.array(final)
mesh.VPos = final
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is not that bad at all.

Here are a few notes:

---

1. Use list comprehension – it's more readable than maps & lambdas

   ```
   indices = [x.ID for x in neighbors]
   ```

---

2. `indices` isn't really necessary. Instead of

   ```
   indices = map(lambda x: x.ID, neighbors)
   z = len(indices)

   help = []
   for j in indices:
       help.append([mesh.VPos[j]])
   final += [sum(x)/z for x in zip(*help)]
   ```

   you can simply do this

   ```
   help = ([mesh.VPos[j.ID]] for j in neighbors)
   z = len(neighbors)
   final.extend(sum(x)/z for x in zip(*help))
   ```

   `help` is a generator expression here, since you don't really need a `list`. That will probably save some overhead of creating the list. You can also avoid creating a new list of `sum(x)/z` and directly append all values to `final` using the `extend` method.

---

3. Instead of reassigning a numpy array to `final`, I'd just do

   ```
   mesh.VPos = np.array(final)
   ```

---

4. I'm not completely sure, but I think the inner lists `[mesh.VPos[j]]` combined with `zip(*help)` will amount to the same as just

   ```
   for j in indices:
       help.append(mesh.VPos[j])
   final += [sum(help) / z]
   ```

---

5. You can create a `numpy.ndarray` right at the beginning instead of using a Python `list` and then converting it.

---

So after the edits it'll look something like this

```
n = mesh.VPos.shape[0]
final = np.empty(n)  # change dtype if you need to

for i in range(n):
    neighbors = mesh.vertices[i].getVertexNeighbors()
    help = (mesh.VPos[j.ID] for j in neighbors)
    final[i] = sum(help) / len(neighbors)

mesh.VPos = final
```

Alternatively you can use `numpy.mean` to compute `sum(help) / len(neighbors)`:

```
n = mesh.VPos.shape[0]
final = np.empty(n)  # change dtype if you need to

for i in range(n):
    neighbors = mesh.vertices[i].getVertexNeighbors()
    help = [mesh.VPos[j.ID] for j in neighbors]
    final[i] = np.mean(help)

mesh.VPos = final
```

Note that you cannot give a generator argument to `numpy.mean`, it has to be a `list` (or anything with `__len__` method).